# why I am getting SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function?

Tags: python, excel, function, syntax-error, yield

I am trying to use PyCharm to read a locked excel file and I used the following code:

```
with open('abcd.xlsm', 'rb') as abcd1:
        excel = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile('abcd.xlsm')
        excel.load_key('1234')
        excel.decrypt(temp)
        abcd1.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        while True:
            lines = abcd1.readline()
            if not lines:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue
            yield lines
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this yield function? I have been getting

> [SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function]

I am new to python so I would appreciate some help, thank you so much!

Comment: Where do you think you're yielding to?

Answer (score 1):

Yield is a keyword that can only be used in a function, you called it outside any function so that won't work

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-yield-keyword/
You could read more about it here or in the official documentations
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement